# Window.opener not working with stripe connect popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, window.opener, stripe-connect

I have stripe connect integrated on my project, stripe verification window opens in popup and when it is closed parent window reloaded.

I was working fine few days ago but now its giving me window.opener is null error 
following is my code

```
window.opener.location.reload();
```

Comment: Same problem here any clues ?

Comment: Not yet, Its happening only in case of stripe, I am using 7 different popups and they all are working fine except stripe.

Comment: Yeah, worked for us a few weeks ago, looks like Stripe did something that detaches the popup from its opener...

Answer (score 4):

Contacted stripe support, and it does seem to come from some security measure they took, here is a part of the answer I got:

> [...] Unfortunately, we don't have a work around for this yet as this change was put in place to prevent a security vulnerability a few months back. [...]

So for now we went to the whole redirect method.

Answer (score -1):

You are calling this statement after the popup is closed. So `window.opener` is giving the null pointer error. 
`self.opener.location.reload();`
`window.close();` or `self.close();`
Like this reload parent window then close the child window